# Filtering out a Value in a column that meets a condition, then sort it in another column

Tags: excel, indexing, row

EDIT:
I am sorry my explanation came out hastily. Let me rewrite it.

This is an experiment with a game where at the end of it, you will receive a score. Based on that score, you might win or lose the game.

My objective is to find out the correlation of wins to score,so first I will need to sort the wins from the losses in Column D.

Columns B and C are manual input. Column D are automated input, thus its where the code I referenced below will be implemented.

The problem lies in the formula being used here as its not resulting in my desired results.

In my excel layout below, you see that Column D is where I want the winning score results to be.

But its not sorting out the winning score from the losses accurately; the resulting scores in column D is coming from both wins and losses at random, for example, in the layout below; Cell D3 is referenced from cell B9 which is actually a Loss. Cell D18 is referenced from cell B13.

Excel layout:

Range B2:B22 Header Inclusive)

```
  B      C      D

2  Score W/L  Sort Wins
3  100   Win     50
4  200   Win     100
5  500   Win     100
6  400   Win     105
7  300   Win     130
8  40    Lose    140
9  50    Lose    200
10 200   Win     200
11 250   Win     200
12 105   Lose    250
13 550   Win     300
14 600   Win     300
15 700   Win     400
16 400   Win     400
17 300   Win     500
18 200   Win     550
19 100   Lose    600
20 140   Lose    700
21 130   Lose   
22 20    Lose




=IFERROR(INDEX(B$3:B$22,SMALL(IF(C$3:C$22="Win",ROW(B$3:B$22)-ROW(B$3)+1),ROW(B1))),"")
```

Again, the following explanation is what I have done to troubleshoot the code I used.

I have tried dissecting each function within formula to test. I am able to produce the correct results I wanted in small scale tests for each of the functions, but as soon as nest the functions in the formula, it will not work.

I am aware that it is an array formula and have used Ctrl Shift Enter.

Looking for some pointers on what went wrong with this formula.

This is what the desired results look like:

```
  B      C      D

2  Score     W/L   Sort Wins
3  100   Win     100
4  200   Win     200
5  500   Win     500
6  400   Win     400
7  300   Win     300
8  40    Lose    200
9  50    Lose    250
10 200   Win     550
11 250   Win     600
12 105   Lose    700
13 550   Win     400
14 600   Win     300
15 700   Win     200
16 400   Win     
17 300   Win     
18 200   Win     
19 100   Lose    
20 140   Lose    
21 130   Lose   
22 20    Lose
```

I am using Excel Online so using VBA to produce the results is not an option for me.

Hopefully this is more clear and thank you in advance.

Rgds,

Sham

Comment: Not clear to me what you want.  The formula you posted will return the winning scores with no skipped rows.  What do you get?  What do you want?

Comment: `I want to sort out the wins from the losses based on game score.` ... what do you mean? Can you post an example of how the data will look  _after_ it's finished? (with an [edit] to your question)

Comment: Just to make sure, Your formula is an Array formula and needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  Are you using Ctrl-Shift-enter?  Is Excel putting `{}` around the formula?

Comment: Hi everyone, apologies for the hasty write-up, I have rewritten the article to be more explanatory. To  Ron Rosenfeld, yes, you are accurate in your assessment. That is the desired outcome but its not happening for some reason which is beyond me and I am trying to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

You question is subject to interpretation due to lack of information but my guess is that you're trying to do this...

[image: example]

What strange sport is this that the names of teams or players aren't tracked along with the scores?

Comment: Hi, its a single team of players. Basically, its a repeat tests to see how well their scores match up with a 'win' scenario. I have rewritten the article to be more explanatory. My apologies that I have not explained well, thank you for the solution provided but that is not the outcome I desired. Refer back to my original post where I have put an example of the desired results.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm trying but can't understand what you're trying to do. `Correlation of wins to score`, do you want a list of scores, with a count of how many winners had that score?